# Dockerized wso2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I was exploring the possibility of using Wso2 API Manager in a dockerized cluster and was pointed to this link. 
https://github.com/gayangunarathne/Docker-compose/tree/master/wso2-products/WSO2APIM/1.10.

In the docker-compose file I see references to svnrepo service. Could you please point me to instructions on how to configure this? Is this really required for Deployment Synchronizer Configuration?

Also any idea how I can access dockerhub.private.wso2.com ? Also any other examples of the distributed patterns of components of API Manager (like gateway,keymanager,store,publisher) in docker containers that are running in the  production environment?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 will soon have their docker images available publicly. 
SVN is only required for dep-sync. For now you can use any svn docker container for that.
We are currently implementing distributed deployment patterns with docker-compose. These will be released once ready.. 
Hope this helps.
Supun

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please share the instructions to set the svn repo for dep-sync?

Comment: Please this for SVN based deployment synchronizer configuration: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer